# $G$ is a finite group and $H \subseteq G$ such that $\forall a,b \in H: ab\in H$. Prove that $H\le G$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

> $G$ is a finite group and $\emptyset \ne H \subseteq G$ such that $\forall a,b \in H:
> ab\in H$. Prove that $H\le G$.

**My attempt:**

Suppose $a\in H$: $a = a\cdot 1_G \in H \Rightarrow 1_G\in H \Rightarrow a\cdot a^{-1}\in H \Rightarrow a^{-1}\in H.$

Associativity is ok, because $G$ is a group.

This seems wrong to me, because this question is marked as a relatively hard one and I solved it using barely 2 lines. Am I doing it right?

Thank you.

Comment: The problem in your proof is that you are using the relation in the wrong direction! You are using
$$ab\in H\implies a\in H \land b\in H$$
which is not what the statement says. The statement is the converse:
$$a\in H \land b\in H\implies ab\in H$$

Comment: Hint: Fix an arbitrary $a \in H$ and prove that $a^n \in H$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, show that among $a^1, a^2,$ ... $, a^{|G|}$, at least one of them is equal to $1$.

Comment: This is a theorem known as The Finite Subgroup Test. See, for instance, Theorem 3.3 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't conclude that $1_G\in H$ that easily. The only thing we know is that if we have *two elements in $H$*, then their product is in $H$. We do not know that if the product of two things are in $H$, then each of the factors are in $H$ (not even if we already know that one of the factors are in $H$).

Instead, to show that $1_G\in H$, you need to consider $a^2, a^3, a^4, \ldots$, show that every one of those is in $H$, and show that $1_G$ is one of them.

Associativity you get for free, as we already know that $G$ is a group, and closure is assumed from the get-go. The only remaining thing is inverses. But that proof is basically the same as the proof for $1_G$, so that shouldn't cause too much of an issue.

Comment: As a hint for the proof of $1_G\in \{a,a^2,a^3,\dots\}$, use the Pidgeon Hole principle!